# jqgrid addrow editrow=false

Tags: jqgrid

Here is my code that adds a line to the grid by pressing the enter key.
All lines are in the add mode  editrow=true.

```
    jQuery("#energy").jqGrid('addRow', { position: "first" });
            jQuery("#energy").jqGrid('bindKeys', {
            "onEnter": function (rowid) {
                jQuery("#energy").jqGrid('addRow');
                    }
           });
```

What you need to specify that prametr editrow=false, when adding rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the [code for `addRow`](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js) always sets the new row to edit mode:

```
addRow : function ( p ) {
        ...
        if(p.useFormatter) {
            $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(p.rowID)+
                              " .ui-inline-edit", 
                              "#"+$.jgrid.jqID($t.p.id)).click();
        } else {
            var opers = $t.p.prmNames,
            oper = opers.oper;
            p.addRowParams.extraparam[oper] = opers.addoper;
            $($t).jqGrid('editRow', p.rowID, p.addRowParams);
            $($t).jqGrid('setSelection', p.rowID);
        }
```

But the good news is that, you should be able to use `saveRow` to get the row out of edit mode. Just make sure you pass a unique row ID for the new row so that you are able to reference it in the next call:

```
 jQuery("#energy").jqGrid('addRow', {rowID: myNewRowID});
 jQuery("#energy").jqGrid('saveRow', myNewRowID);
```

If you have problems with `saveRow`, you can also try `restoreRow`.

Does that help?